# Самое короткое совпадение +1

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Хочу выделить самое короткое совпадение, но только чтобы он брал не первый div, а после него идущий.

Вот например регулярка для выделения самого первого совпадение. А мне нужно на +1 больше

```
(?<=item_description)[\w\W]*?(?=</div>)


 <div class="item_description">
                Описание объявы
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        </script>

                                </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: чтобы найти заданный элемент, можно использовать css-выборку: `div.item_descriptor + div` (div, который следует сразу за  `<div class="item_description">..</div>`). Можно использовать [`x ~ y` вместо `x + y`, если `y` элемент следует за `x` (не обязательно *сразу*)](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).  В более сложных случаях можно xpath-выражениями воспользоваться, чтобы выбрать нужный элемент.

Answer (score 4):

[Еще один герой, пытающийся парсить HTML регулярными выражениями.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Просто не нужно этого делать. [Грамматика HTML нерегулярна(2 уровень)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) и стоит просто взять любой DOM или XML парсер. Все.

[image: СТОЙ!]

P.S. ТС не подумай ничего личного, просто это реально плохая идея и расхожее заблуждение, треды с которым всплывают постоянно(за сегодня было два) и которые мне уже порядком поднадоели. Вот скажем js однострочник который легко вытащит "Описание объявы" из первого diva в этом HTML.

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("item_description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Это ведь проще чем пытаться вот этим:

```
<\/?([A-Za-z][^\s>\/]*)(?:=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s>]+)|[^>])*(?:>|$)
```

Вытащить теги, например, из такой конструкции:

```
<script> a<b; if(div>0) alert("</div>"); </script>
```

Comment: Чувак, а ты не думал что у него может не JS, а какой-нибудь C++?  
Да, ужасно что не поставлен тэг нужного языка (или в вопросе), но всё же даже с этим нужно считаться...

Comment: Да думал конечно, но метки то нет никакой, я и решил взять самое популярное.  Хотя сейчас наверное в любом языке есть что-нибудь для парса HTML.

Comment: У него точно не js, потому что в js такого нет: `(?<=`

Comment: Да какая разница, какой именно язык.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это [`(?<=`] относится к регулярным вырежениям, а они в JS есть.

Comment: @Etki, большая. Укажи ТС язык, ему могли бы соответственно подсказать как парсить или дать ссылку на нужный парсер.

Comment: @TheDoctor, регулярные выражения в js есть, но этой конкретной конструкции в джаваскриптовых регулярных выражениях нет. Проверь - увидишь SyntaxError.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Честно говоря, никогда конкретно эту фичу в JS не юзал, так что может ты и прав, только странно это - можно понять отсутствие модификатора, но такую конструкцию...

Comment: @TheDoctor, эта конструкция - это просмотр назад (точнее, один из его видов). Наличие таких конструкций позволяет при проверке выходить за множество регулярных языков (кстати, отсюда вытекает подозрение про неверность утверждения о невозможности распарсить так html). По стандарту от регулярок в js не требуется их поддержка (хотя и не запрещена). Это относится ко всем расширенным конструкциям, выводящим за пределы регулярных языков, например `(?=` и `(?!` есть, а `(?<=`, `(?<!` и условного поиска нет. Вроде, в C# есть. Другие языки прокомментировать не готов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Я знаю что эта конструкция делает, но думал это стандарт ядра регулярок...
Парсить HTML лично мне часто лучше, чем скармливать стороннему парсеру - ради одной строчки качегарить парсер? Да ну :)

Comment: `<script> a<b; if(div>0) alert("</div>"); </script>` такие конструкции почти нереальны. Тем более, скритп-то уж точно однозначно удаляется регулярками (как и html-комментарий), в отличие от других тегов. Для большинства ситуаций регуляркой можно легко вытащить нужный кусок.